# JQuery - Unable to access data of multiple View elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Question Background:**

I have an MVC app which has a view containing 3 Panels. In each respective Panel is a single button that when clicked needs to pass data set from a passed Model object within the Panels to a method on a controller called 'AddToCart'.

**Issue:**

Here is the code of the view:

```
   <div class="row mePadding" id="features">
    <input id="productId" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(0).Id">
    <input id="productImage" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(0).ProductImage">
    <input id="productBrand" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(0).ProductBrand">
    <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title boldFeatures" id="productName">@(Model.ElementAt(0).ProductName)</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = @Model.ElementAt(0).Id })"><img src="~/Images/@(Model.ElementAt(0).ProductImage)" class="img-circle" id="featuresImages" alt="Work"></a>
                <p>@(Model.ElementAt(0).ProductSummary)</p>
                <p id="productPrice">@(Model.ElementAt(0).ProductPrice)</p>

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block AddToCart" type="button" data-name="@Model.ElementAt(0).ProductName" data-price="@Model.ElementAt(0).ProductPrice" value="Add to Cart" id="addToCart" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="productId" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(1).Id">
    <input id="productImage" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(1).ProductImage">
    <input id="productBrand" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(1).ProductBrand">
    <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title boldFeatures" id="productName">@(Model.ElementAt(1).ProductName)</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = @Model.ElementAt(1).Id })"><img src="~/Images/@(Model.ElementAt(1).ProductImage)" class="img-circle" id="featuresImages" alt="Work"></a>
                <p>@(Model.ElementAt(1).ProductSummary)</p>
                <p id="productPrice">@(Model.ElementAt(1).ProductPrice)</p>

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block AddToCart" type="button" data-name="@Model.ElementAt(1).ProductName" data-price="@Model.ElementAt(1).ProductPrice" value="Add to Cart" id="addToCart" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="productId" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(2).Id">
    <input id="productImage" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(2).ProductImage">
    <input id="productBrand" type="hidden" value="@Model.ElementAt(2).ProductBrand">
    <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title boldFeatures" id="productName">@(Model.ElementAt(2).ProductName)</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = @Model.ElementAt(2).Id })"><img src="~/Images/@(Model.ElementAt(2).ProductImage)" class="img-circle" id="featuresImages" alt="Work"></a>
                <p>@(Model.ElementAt(2).ProductSummary)</p>
                <p id="productPrice">@(Model.ElementAt(2).ProductPrice)</p>

                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block AddToCart" type="button" data-name="@Model.ElementAt(2).ProductName" data-price="@Model.ElementAt(2).ProductPrice" value="Add to Cart" id="addToCart" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

  $(this).click(function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "id": $('#productId').val(),
            "name": $('#productName').text(),
            "qty": "1",
            "price": $('#productPrice').text(),
            "brand": $('#productBrand').val(),
            "image": $('#productImage').val()
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is that it dosent matter which button I press on the 3 Panels the Model data set in the first Panel is always sent to the controller 'AddToCart' method.

I tried the following but this did not work:

```
"id": $(this).get('#productId').val()
```

Any help with this would be great.

***EDIT - 12/02/2015***

View now generates Panels through a for loop - currently set to 9 as thats how many items I want displayed on the view:

```
    <div class="row mePadding" id="features">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-4 feature">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title boldFeatures">@(Model.ElementAt(i).ProductName)</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = @Model.ElementAt(i).Id })"><img src="~/Images/@(Model.ElementAt(i).ProductImage)" class="img-circle" id="featuresImages" alt="Work"></a>
                    <p class="summary">@(Model.ElementAt(i).ProductSummary)</p>
                    <p class="price">@(Model.ElementAt(i).ProductPrice)</p>

                    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block AddToCart" type="button" data-id="@Model.ElementAt(0).Id" value="Add to Cart" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

JQuery Button click:

I've removed the logic to actually post the ID to the `AddToCart` method on the controller so I can just check the ID's when the button is clicked.

```
<script>
 $(".AddToCart").click(function () {

    var id = $(this).data('id');

    alert(id);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Your generating invalid html with duplicate `id` attributes. `$('#productId').val()` will always return the value of the first element with `id = "productId"`. Remove the `id` attributes (use a class name instead) and get the values by using selectors that get the element relative to the button clicked.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your reply. I have removed the `id` attributes and have added class name names instead. In my JQuery I'm still calling this and am attempting to to use the following to get the data using the `.prodName` selector - `var productName= $(".prodName").text();` This again gives me all of the data in the View with the `.test` class name. Can you elaborate when you say 'get the element relative to the button clicked'?

Comment: Are you wanting to trigger this when your click one of the buttons with the value "Add to Cart"? Its a bit hard to understand why you have not just generated the html in a loop instead of repeating it 3 times and also why you even have hidden inputs at all.

Comment: Also, why are you posting back all that data - surely you only need to post back the product ID (a normally you would also post a quantity but you don't seem to have any input for that)

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is purely a test, I could of - and have in other views - sent the list of product item objects from my controller to the view then used a for loop to build the Panels. You are correct that I want the call to trigger everytime the 'AddToCart' buttons are clicked. In terms of posting all the data, yes I could just post the ID then query the DB for the product item in the controller method then add this to my backend cart object but I thought as I have the data ready to go in the view I'd just post it back.

Comment: Posting all that extra data is bad practice and will degrade performance - its usually better to get the data from the database again . I'll post an answer shortly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should use loop to display you products (and dont give you elements an `id` attribute as this generated invalid html)

```
@foreach(var product in Model)
{
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <h3 class="panel-title boldFeatures">@product.ProductName</h3>
    <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetail", "Product", new { id = product.Id })">.....</a>
    <p calss="summary">@product.ProductSummary)</p>
    <p class="price">@product.ProductPrice)</p>
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block AddToCart" type="button" data-id="product.ID" value="Add to Cart" />
  </div>
}
```

Note the products ID value has been added to the button as a `data-` attribute. Note you could add additional properties e.g. `data-productprice = "@product.ProductPrice"` but since you have already rendered these values, you can also access these with relative selectors (does not seem much sense duplicating them). In any case, its only the products ID which should be posted back anyway (and usually the value from a textbox indicating the desired quantity).

Then handle the click event of the button

```
var url = '@Url.Action("AddToCart")';
$('.AddToCart').click(function() {
  // Get the product ID
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  // Could extract other values using above method or using relative selectors, for example
  var price = $(this).closest('panel-default').find('.price').text();
  // Post back the product ID
  $.post(url, { id: id }, function(data) {
    // do something with the returned value?
  });
  // or $.post(url, { id: id, price: price, etc }, function(data) { ...
});
```

And you POST method would be

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddToCart(int ID) // add other parameters as required
{
  // Add the product to the cart
  // Return something indicating success?
  return Json(true);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your example. I have made the changes to my view but still the issue presists with the first product ID from the model being passed to the cart. I've updated my question to show my changes.

Comment: That because you button is always setting the ID to `1` by using `data-id="@Model.ElementAt(0).Id"` (it should be `@Model.ElementAt(i).id` or more simply `@Model[i].id`)

Comment: **cringe**! Can't believe I missed that! Changed all the other elements to the value of `i` bar that! Many thanks for your time on this Stephen!